# c# regex everything after n-th occurence of capital letter

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm having a hard time with regular expressions in C#.
I have a joined string with name and surname, and need only the first letter of name and a surname:

```
string input = "NameSurname";
string output = "NSurname";
```

So basically it's always first letter of input string, plus what comes after second occurence of capital letter.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733/327083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why people are down-voting these posts.

Try this

```
var name = Regex.Replace("NameSurname", @"^(\w)[^A-Z]*(.*)", "$1$2")
```

^(\w) matches the first character and retains it in $1.

[^A-Z]* matches any subsequent characters that aren't upper case letters.

(.*) matches all subsequent characters and retains them in $2.

So we replace "NameSurname" with $1="N" + $2="Surname"

Comment: No idea who is downvoting the answers, but it would certainly be helpful if they explained what's wrong with the answer.

Comment: @MatthewWatson 5 years and 36k... and it's not obvious?  SO is not a regex mechanical turk.  The question is lazy and answers like this just feed that laziness.  There is no programming problem, there is no solution - no teaching, no learning, no explanation, and no help to anyone facing a similar problem in the future.  It's crap all the way through - "Do my work for me".

Comment: @J... I didn't say that I didn't know the reason, but it's not me that's downvoting so it's not up to me to explain. I was merely pointing out that it would be useful for the people being downvoted who have *not* been here for 5 years. Can you see the difference there? I treat this site as a place to help and educate people, not to silently berate them for not knowing all the rules...

Comment: Thank you @MathewWatson. You're right - a constructive comment is much more useful that a down-vote. I've amended my answer to make it instructive having understood the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use regex? It might be easier to use Linq.

For example:

```
var charsFromSecondUppercaseChar = input.Skip(1).SkipWhile(c => !char.IsUpper(c));
string output = input[0] + new string(charsFromSecondUppercaseChar.ToArray());
```